# TyphoonOptionMatcher with conformsToProtocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

It would be nice if I could use matcher to select definition based on protocol, for example:

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForViewModel:(id <IViewModel>)viewModel
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withOption:viewModel matcher:^(TyphoonOptionMatcher *matcher)
    {
        [matcher conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ILoginViewModel) use:[self loginViewController]];
        [matcher conformsToProtocol:@protocol(IMainViewModel) use:[self mainScreenViewController]];
        [matcher defaultUse:[self emptyScreen]];
    }];
}
```

Is it possible to do with what Typhoon has right now or maybe with some workarounds?

Thank you.

Edit:
I've made some additions to TyphoonOptionMatch and TyphoonOptionMatcher to have conformsToProtocol option, is it worth it to create a PR?

TyphoonOptionMatch

```
@property (nonatomic) Protocol *proto;
....
+ (id)matchWithConformsToProto:(Protocol *)proto injection:(id)injection;
```

TyphoonOptionMatcher

```
- (void)conformsToProto:(Protocol *)aProtocol use:(id)injection
...
- (TyphoonOptionMatch *)matchForValue:(id)value {
...
    BOOL isConformProto = (match.proto && [value conformsToProtocol:match.proto]);
```

Comment: Hi, Emil! Looks like a nice feature to have - I've added the corresponding issue: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/454. It would be nice to see a PR from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is out in 3.4.5 [release](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/releases/tag/3.4.5)

```
[matcher caseConformsToProtocol:@protocol(IMainViewModel) 
                            use:[self mainScreenViewController]];
```